# Tabulator - Styling empty cells

Tags: tabulator

I'm trying to style only tabulator empty cells.
I tried with a custom formatter but it seems to be called only on cells with data.
Any suggestion on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to process fields without data just fine ...

https://jsfiddle.net/udpr2680/

```
new Tabulator("#tabulator", {
  data:[{id:4957},{id:39857,price:100}],
  columns: [
    { title: "number", field: "id"},
    { title: "price", field: "price",formatter: function(c,fP,onR) { let p = c.getData().price; if (p === undefined) return "undefined"; return p; } },
    ],
});
```

Comment: Ok, I found where the issue laid: I had my "custom formatter" which was a variation over the standard "money" formatter and the standard "money" formatter just returns an "emptyToSpace" for NaN values, that's why the following lines were not executed and I couldn't see the output (and that made me think that the value was not processed at all). Thank you very much for pointing out the correct behaviour anyway!